# Could not find module 'FBSDKCoreKit' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk

I have installed Facebook SDK using Swift Package Manager. While building the app it shows the following error message:

```
Could not find module 'FBSDKCoreKit' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator
```

While i played with the settings i have found this error is due to the addition of **arm64** under Excluded Architecture. I had added this because I had installed Postman with POD and it was throwing the error message:

```
No such module 'Tabman'.
```

To make Tabman work i need to add arm64 under Excluded Architecture and to make Facebook SDK work i need to remove. In short i cannot make both work. Please suggest appropriate solution. Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using M1 Mac Book Pro with Xcode Version 12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did tried to open xcode using Rosetta but it was not working. I tried multiple times and finally worked. Yes right click on xcode and click info and choose Open using Rosetta worked!!!